# List Matches from Random Matrix

Tags: postgresql, matrix

I created an “x” by “y” matrix with random matches denoted by “O”.  For values 1-5, "O" denotes a "preference to match".  A "match" occurs only if both values reciprocate the preference (1 and 2 are a "match" because both prefer the other, while 1 and 3 are NOT a match because the preference isn't reciprocated).

[Visualization](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uhS1D.png)

Best attempt at SQL:

```
    create table variable1 (
    match1 binary,
    match2 binary,
    match3 binary,
    match4 binary,
    match5 binary
    ),

    create table variable2 (
    match1 binary,
    match2 binary,
    match3 binary,
    match4 binary,
    match5 binary
    ),

    create table variable3 (
    match1 binary,
    match2 binary,
    match3 binary,
    match4 binary,
    match5 binary
    ),

    create table variable4 (
    match1 binary,
    match2 binary,
    match3 binary,
    match4 binary,
    match5 binary
    ),

    create table variable5 (
    match1 binary,
    match2 binary,
    match3 binary,
    match4 binary,
    match5 binary
    ),

    insert into variable1(
    null,
    O,
    -,
    O,
    O
    ),

    insert into variable2(
    O,
    null,
    O,
    O,
    O
    ),

    insert into variable3(
    O,
    -,
    null,
    O,
    -
    ),

insert into variable4(
    O,
    -,
    O,
    null,
    O
    ),

insert into variable5(
    O,
    O,
    O,
    O,
    null
    ),
```

In only the 5x5 matrix,

1 and 2 match
1 and 4 match
1 and 5 match
2 and 5 match
3 and 5 match
4 and 5 match
1 and 3 do NOT match
2 and 3 do NOT match
2 and 4 do NOT match
3 and 4 do NOT match

First question - Is there a "match" query that lists the unique 1x1 set of matches?

Second question - Is there an "iterative match" query that lists the unique set of matches after “z” iterations?

For example, after 1 match iteration, the result would be the list of 6 matches above.  After 2 iterations,  the result would be a group of 1, 4, and 5, since 1 and 4 both match with 5.

I'd like the function to apply to an “x” by “y” matrix.  I'd like the results to be "z" lists, corresponding to the number of iterations, with each list having z+1 numbers within each group.

I am using Postgresql 11.4.

Here is a link for an explanation of the first matching function in Excel:

[Excel Explanation](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/1103811-matrix-matching-function.html)

Unfortunately, I don't have the reference VBA figured out quite yet.  I'd rather simply put this all in Postgres.

Comment: `I don't have [somebody else's approach] figured out quite yet. I'd rather simply put this all in Postgres.` What obstacle are you stuck at with the latter?

Comment: @greybeard - I have the Excel function for the first match (as noted in the external link), but I do not have the SQL.  Nor do I have the SQL for the second, third, fourth... zth iterations.